# Fixture not loading in Django

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

Settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

FIXTURE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/deals/fixtures/'),
)
```

test_deals.py:

```
import unittest
from deals.models import Retailer
import django.test

class TestRetailer(django.test.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        fixtures = ['deals_test_data.json']
        self.bestbuy = Retailer(Retailer.objects.get(pk=1))

    def test_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.bestbuy.name, 'Best Buy US')
```

Project structure:

```
project
  - deals
     - fixtures
         - deals_test_data.json
     - tests
         - test_deals.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danny/PycharmProjects/askarby/deals/tests/test_deals.py", line 10, in setUp
    self.bestbuy = Retailer(Retailer.objects.get(pk=1))
  File "/home/danny/.virtualenvs/AskArby/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/danny/.virtualenvs/AskArby/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
deals.models.DoesNotExist: Retailer matching query does not exist.

Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried not using FIXTURES_DIR but instead using fixtures=['../deals_test_data.jason']. I've tried removing the slashes at the front and back of the string in my FIXTURES_DIR. No joy.

How can I make my fixtures load?

Comment: This line needs to be fixed: `self.bestbuy = Retailer(Retailer.objects.get(pk=1))`. Instead, it needs to be: `self.bestbuy = Retailer.objects.get(pk=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixtures were loading, but my code to retrieve the object must have been off. This nailed it:

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
from deals.models import Retailer

class TestRetailer(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['deals_test_data.json']

    def test_loaded(self):
        s = Retailer.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEquals(s.name, "Best Buy US")
```